# How does photonic propulsion work?

Tags: mass, laser, photonics

I just heard about the photonic propulsion and it looks like light may have a mass ! Which is known by the name of "relative mass".

The question is way too generic but here are more precision:

- How could you amplify the relative mass of a laser beam?
- How could you calculate the relative mass before and after the amplification ?
- How such an amplificator (array?) does even works and looks like ?
- Which kind of laser should we use to get the bigger mass ?

As you can see, I don't know anything on this subject and can't find much vulgarized informations about the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can find some information in this video or in its references : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtPBqJ8XmWQ

Comment: Photons have momentum but not mass.

Answer (score 1):

You can not amplify a beam. you have to start with a strong beam.  the higher the intensity of the beam the higher the mass , the lower the wavelength, the higher the Maas of one Photon. you better argue withe the momentum instead of the mass, the momentum of one photon is h*f/c.